# Concat strings using Formatter Class in Java

Tags: java, string, printing, output, formatter

I'm having a problem trying to format a field.

(`s` in my example represents space).
I need to make this: `sssssssss$37,189.50`

I tried using like this `$%1$,.f` but I get this: `$37,189.50sssssssss`

I tried also make like this `$%1$18s` but I get this: `$sssssssss37189.50`

Comment: You can't create pattern which will generate `sss[litera][userData]`. Instead try combining literal with usersData before passing it to formatter, something like `format(yourPattern, [literal]+[userData])`